# How is Google Translate able to translate texts of arbitrarily large length?

Tags: recurrent-neural-networks, transformer, machine-translation

Sequence-to-sequence models with attention are known to be limited by a maximum sequence length. So how can we handle sequences of arbitrarily large size? Do we just set a very large maximum sequence length?

Answer (score 2):

You simply split the sequence into smaller sequences; while there are some long-distance dependencies in language, that is generally not a problem for this.

A sentence would typically be short enough, and very long sentences are composed of shorter clauses which would form independent units (albeit connected with each other).

Comment: How would this "splitting" be done in practice? How are these clauses found? Would this require another model or is it just a matter of defining a set of segmentation rules?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd guess it would just be by length. I doubt that there would much linguistic knowledge behind it, as it would generally be language independent. Maybe on commas or other punctuation marks.